# Xvnc, Xinetd and Jaunty = grey screen mania

Tags: vnc

I've been trying for a 'while' to get this bug out ...

In a fresh minimal install of jaunty; apt-get install xinetd vnc4server openbox. Edited a service file in /etc/xinetd.d/Xvnc : 
service Xvnc

```
{ 
        type = UNLISTED
        disable = no
        socket_type = stream
        protocol = tcp
        wait = no
        user = root
        server = /usr/bin/Xvnc
        server_args = -inetd :1 -query ::1 -geometry 800x600 -once -fp /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc -DisconnectClients=0 -NeverShared -securitytypes=none -extension XFIXES
        port = 5901
}
```

Set up a xstartup file in ~/.vnc/xstartup :

```
#!/bin/sh
openbox-session &
xsetroot -solid grey
xterm -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
```

All i get is a grey screen (old X style) whenever i try changing any option, tweaked over and over.

But,

If i simply run a :

```
vncserver :1
```

I'm able to connectm xterm shows .. etc.

Any idea ?

Comment: Ok, the more I play around with this, the more I think xinetd is the wrong particular hammer for this problem.  Any particular reason you're using it over just, say, starting vncserver in rc.local?

Comment: Mmh not sure to get your idea; i'll have let's say 100 users; each user will have his own 'desktop', they'll connect using a web browser (java vnc); i'll limit access to the browser with username password; each user will have his own vnc port (launched by his own vnc instance). See ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to set up a display manager such as GDM.  When Xvnc is starting up, it tries to communicate with a running display manager via XDMCP.  That's what the `-query ::1` option is in your xinetd file.  I've set up GDM on Hardy before, and it worked pretty well.  Give this a try:

Install GDM if it's not already installed.

Edit */etc/gdm/gdm-cdd.conf*:

- In the section `[xdmcp]`, set the `Enabled` option to **true**.
- In the section `[daemon]`, set the `RemoteGreeter` option to the same as the `Greeter` option.  This isn't strictly necessary, but it's prettier.

Restart GDM.

Then try connecting again.  You should see a login screen where you can enter your username and password.  If that doesn't work, try changing `-query ::1` to `-query 127.0.0.1`.  It may be having trouble with IPv6.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; my concern is memory; i'd like to use the minimal environnement, i think setting gdm will add extra useless memory.

I added the ::1 because of this post (http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-795036.html).

Why is it working when running from command line and not from xinetd; that's the question :)

Comment: Oh one more thing; i don't want users to 'login' to their account providing username and password; this setup is for a kiosk, will let users only login and use some applications, for example firefox

Comment: If you don't want to use a display manager, then you shouldn't use `-query`.  That's what that is for.  Remove that and change the `user` field to the user where you were running vncserver.

Comment: Tried; still getting the grey X display ...

Comment: is there a 'tool' or how to find out what's going wrong ... nothing in logs

Comment: The reason you're seeing different results is vncserver is doing a lot more than just starting the server.  Xvnc, which xinetd is calling, is *only* the server.  It doesn't start other programs, it just waits for connections.